# Code coverage of apex callout/test class

Tags: unit-test, callout

I am trying to cover the mentioned callout but I am able to achieve 59%. I am unable to cover first method ie **getMoog** and  all the **if statements**.

I know there are lots of errors in my code as I am new to technology but currently its working for me,

please suggest me to make my code more and more mature and to achieve around 75% code coverage.

```
class Moogsoft {

@future (callout=true)
public static  void getMoog(String inc, Decimal moog,id iid) {
    HttpResponse  res = authToken();
    String authT;
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME){
                String fieldName = parser.getText();
                parser.nextToken();
                 if(fieldName == 'auth_token' ) {
                    authT = parser.getText();
                    system.debug('++++++++++'+authT);
                }
            }
        }
    system.debug('####'+authT);
    HttpResponse  firstc = firstCall(inc,moog,authT);
    system.debug('####first'+firstc.getbody());
    HttpResponse secondC = secondCall(inc,moog,authT);
    system.debug('####'+secondC);
    HttpResponse thirdC = thirdCall(iid,moog,authT);
    system.debug('####'+thirdC);

}
 public static httpResponse authToken() {
    String URL1 = 'abc.com';
    HttpResponse resData = HTTPCallout(URL1, 'GET');
    System.debug('Response from Moog: ('+resData.getStatusCode()+')'+resData.getBody());
       if(resData.getStatusCode()>299) {
        String error = 'Failed getting a request token. HTTP Code = '+resData.getStatusCode()+
                        '. Message: '+resData.getStatus()+'. Response Body: '+resData.getBody();
        system.debug('failed'+error);
           return resdata;
        } 

      else {
        return resData;
        }
 }
public static httpResponse firstCall(String a1,Decimal b1,String c1) {
    String aa = a1;
    Decimal bb = b1;
    String cc = c1;
    System.debug('####'+cc);
    System.debug('####'+aa);
    String URL2 = 'abc.com'';
    HttpResponse res = HTTPCallout(URL2, 'POST');
    System.debug('Response from Code request: ('+res.getStatusCode()+')'+res.getBody());

    if(res.getStatusCode()>299) {
        String error = 'Request failed error.HTTP Code = '+res.getStatusCode()+
                    '. Message: '+res.getStatus()+'. Response Body: '+res.getBody();
        System.debug('##### Failed: '+error);
        return res;
    }


    return res;

    }

public static httpResponse secondCall(String a2,Decimal b2,String c2) {
    String aa = a2;
    Decimal bb = b2;
    String cc =  c2;


 String URL3 = 'abc.com';


    HttpResponse resT = HTTPCallout(URL3, 'POST');
    System.debug('Response from Code request: ('+resT.getStatusCode()+')'+resT.getBody());

    if(resT.getStatusCode()>299) {
        String error = 'Request failed error.HTTP Code = '+resT.getStatusCode()+
                    '. Message: '+resT.getStatus()+'. Response Body: '+resT.getBody();
        System.debug('##### Failed: '+error);
        return resT;
    }


     system.debug('success');
    return resT;

}

public static httpResponse thirdCall(id a2,Decimal b2,String c2) {
    id aa = a2;
    Decimal bb = b2;
    String cc =  c2;
    System.debug('3rd call');

  String URL3 = 'abc.com';

    HttpResponse resm = HTTPCallout(URL3, 'POST');
    System.debug('Response from Code request: ('+resm.getStatusCode()+')'+resm.getBody());

    if(resm.getStatusCode()>299) {
        String error = 'Request failed error.HTTP Code = '+resm.getStatusCode()+
                    '. Message: '+resm.getStatus()+'. Response Body: '+resm.getBody();
        System.debug('##### Failed: '+error);
        return resm ;
    }



    system.debug('sucessfull');
    return resm;
}

public Static HttpResponse HTTPCallout(String EndPoint, String Method) {
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(EndPoint);
    req.setMethod(Method);
    HttpResponse res = null;
    res = h.send(req);
    return res;
}
}
```

Below is my test class.

```
@isTest
   public class MoogsoftTest {
     static testMethod void moogcallout()
     {
    // Create the mock response based on a static resource
StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
    mock.setStaticResource('TestResponse1');
    mock.setStatusCode(200);
    mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
   // Associate the callout with a mock response
  Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
   // Call method to test

    HttpResponse result = Moogsoft.authToken();
   // Verify mock response is not null
 System.assertNotEquals(null,result, 'The callout returned a null response.');
  // String error = 'Failed getting a request token. HTTP Code = '+result.getStatusCode()+
       //                 '. Message: '+result.getStatus()+'. Response Body: '+result.getBody();
       // system.debug('failed'+error);
 System.assertEquals(200,result.getStatusCode(),result);

   HttpResponse res = Moogsoft.firstCall('ca5c44d8a9df405486f41e8dde87f8fb',12345,'0004321');
   System.assertNotEquals(null,res, 'The callout returned a null response.');
   System.assertEquals(200,res.getStatusCode(),result);

   HttpResponse rep = Moogsoft.secondCall('ca5c44d8a9df405486f41e8dde87f8fb',12345,'0004321');
   System.assertNotEquals(null,rep, 'The callout returned a null response.');
   System.assertEquals(200,res.getStatusCode(),result);

    HttpResponse rem = Moogsoft.thirdCall('a1TO0000002j3yb',12345,'0004321');
   System.assertNotEquals(null,rem, 'The callout returned a null response.');
   System.assertEquals(200,rem.getStatusCode(),result);




   }
 }
```

Please help
Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the method you are unable to cover is a `@future` method you need to wrap the code that executes that method in `test.startTest()` and test.stopTest()`

Since you only get one bite at the apple per se when doing this you will need to break out your tests into smaller methods. In addition, breaking the tests into functional units helps you to test all facets of your business / process logic in manageable chunks.

Example:

```
test.startTest()
   Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
   Moogsoft.getMoog(...your params...);
test.stopTest();

....your asserts....
```

> Each test method is allowed to call this method only once. Any code
>   that executes after the stopTest method is assigned the original
>   limits that were in effect before startTest was called. All
>   asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected by
>   the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes are
>   run synchronously

[Test Class - StopTest()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_stopTest)